# Akka RestartSource does not restart

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

```
object TestSource {
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def buildSource = {
      println("fresh")
      Source(List(() => 1,() => 2,() => 3,() => {
        println("crash")
      throw new RuntimeException(":(((")
      }))
    }
    val restarting = RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
      minBackoff = Duration(1, SECONDS) ,
      maxBackoff = Duration(1, SECONDS),
      randomFactor = 0.0,
      maxRestarts = 10
    )(() => {
      buildSource
    })

     implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem           = ActorSystem()
     implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

    restarting.runWith(Sink.foreach(e => println(e())))

  }
}
```

The code above prints: 1,2,3, crash
Why does my source not restart?
This is pretty much a 1:1 copy of the official documentation.

edit:

I also tried

```
    val rs = RestartSink.withBackoff[() => Int](
      Duration(1, SECONDS),
      Duration(1, SECONDS),
      0.0,
      10
    )(_)
    val rsDone = rs(() => {
      println("???")
      Sink.foreach(e => println(e()))
    })
    restarting.runWith(rsDone)
```

but still get no restarts

Answer (score 1):

This is because the exception is triggered outside of the `buildSource` `Source` in the `Sink.foreach` when you call the functions emitted from the `Source`.

Try this:

```
    val restarting = RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
      minBackoff = Duration(1, SECONDS) ,
      maxBackoff = Duration(1, SECONDS),
      randomFactor = 0.0,
      maxRestarts = 10
      )(() => {
        buildSource
         .map(e => e()) //call the functions inside the RestartSource
      })
```

That way your exception will happen inside the inner `Source` wrapped by `RestartSource` and the restarting mechanism will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

The source doesn't restart because your source never fails, therefore never needs to restart.

The exception gets thrown when `Sink.foreach` evaluates the function it received.

As artur noted, if you can move the failing bit into the source, you can wrap everything up to the sink in the `RestartSource`.

While it won't help for this contrived example (as restarting a sink doesn't result in resending previously sent messages), wrapping the sink in a `RestartSink` may be useful in real-world cases where this sort of thing can happen (off the top of my head, streams from Kafka blowing up because the offset commit in a sink failed (e.g. after a rebalance) should be an example of such a case).

An alternative, if you want to restart the whole stream if any part fails, and the stream materializes as a `Future`, you can implement retry-with-backoff on the failed future.

Comment: added this case to the question

Comment: What happens when you add an element to the source after the crash element?  Otherwise, what could very well happen is that since the source has completed (it's emitted all that it can emit) there's no need to restart.

Comment: From the docs for `RestartSource`: "the wrapped Sink can... be completed by feeding a completion into this Sink... [which] will terminate and not be restarted. This can be triggered simply by the upstream completing."

Answer (score 0):

Source just never crashes, as already said here.
You are actually crashing you sink, not a source with this statement `e => e()`

this happens when applying lambda above to last element of source:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: :(((
```

Here's the same stream without unhandled exception in sink:

...
RestartSource.withBackoff(
...

```
restarting.runWith(
  Sink.foreach(e => {
    def i: Int = try{ e() } catch {
      case t: Throwable =>
        println(t)
        -1
    }
    println(i)
  })
)
```

Works perfectly.